# Handling Cursor Through Voice in Android

Tags: android, voice-recognition, clipboardmanager

I am new in android and trying to Access particular line through Voice Recognition. I am developing an Editor and now going to implement cut,copy and paste using Voice commands. Now actually what problem i am facing is that want to go particular line and select the words what i want and then i'll handle the cut,copy and paste through ClipboardManager. Hope I'll get the Logic.

Comment: Are the edit text boxes in your own app?

Comment: Yes.Just gave the input through Voice command as a Text but trying to handle specific commands like "Go to Line number 8" etc. Means just want to know how can i select particular word through voice. Expecting the logic only.

Comment: You'll have to write a lot of logic to interpret all of the possible words inside the edit text, along with the spoken commands of delete, change, update etc. A user could say "Go to line 6 and change the letter T to a capital" or "Change zebra to horse". There is no easy way to do this other than some very smart code. I doubt anyone has this already. The line wrapping will also change dependent on device size, so line 6 won't be the same on a tablet as a small phone.

Comment: @brandall: Can you give me simple logic to handle this like "Go to Line 6" and the cursor will be there. First give the simple idea then i'll concentrate on big like you told earlier. And i am trying this code on NEXUS 5. so primary goal is need to run this code on that device only.